# Is it possible to have Netbeans format keep the @FXML annotation inline with fields?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to have my @FXML annotations inline with my field declarations, and still be able to use the Netbeans format option (shift + ^ + F).  However, it always reformats them to be on the line above my declaration wasting space as depicted in before and after examples below.  Does anyone know how to do this in Netbeans?

This is the code in the format that I like and want to keep.

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TextField usernameTextField;
    @FXML private TextField visiblePasswordTextField;
    @FXML private PasswordField passwordField;
    @FXML private CheckBox showPasswordCheckBox;
    @FXML private Button login;
```

This is the code after running format option in Netbeans.

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField usernameTextField;
    @FXML
    private TextField visiblePasswordTextField;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox showPasswordCheckBox;
    @FXML
    private Button login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration setting in NetBeans which does exactly what you want:

- Select **Tools > Options > Editor**, then click the **Formatting** tab.
- Select **Java** from the **Language** drop list, then **Wrapping** from the **Category** drop list.
- Locate the **Annotations** option in the left column, then change its default setting of **Always** to **Never**:

  [image: annotation setting]
- Click the **Apply** button and then close the **Options** window.

Once that is done you can place annotations on the same line as code and reformatting will not force them onto a separate line.

I didn't specifically test `@FXML`, but I verified this with some trivial code which has a couple of method annotations:

```
package javaapplication10;

public class JavaApplication10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println("Foo.dummy() = " + foo.dummy());

    }

    @Deprecated public int dummy() {
        return 42;
    }

}

class Foo extends JavaApplication10 {

    @Override public int dummy() {
        return 41;
    }

}
```

There is also an **Annotation Arguments** option (shown in the screen shot above), though since it has a default setting of **Never** you would probably never want to change it.